# Preventing API users from using some methods

Tags: java, oop, exception, architecture

Hi I'm implementing a given design in java. Basically I have an abstract class which is called base and I have a number of concrete classes which are extending Base and implementing an interface from a different package. Each concrete class will be implementing a different interface. Now these interfaces contain both event-based and non event-based method signatures in them. My question here is; I'm only expected to implement non-event based methods in my concrete classes, however because of the implements keyword java forces me to insert an auto generated method body, which is basically return null. They might be implementing those event based methods later on but not at the moment. What would be an appropriate way to let the API user know that these methods do not contain an implementation. Here are my thoughts;

1. Use deprecated keyword
2. Create an exception class and throw that exception inside of the method and let the API user handle it.

I do not have the option of making changes to the existing architecture. Any idea really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Some kind of `NotYetImplemented` exception, as well as thoroughly documenting the fact that the methods currently do nothing and shouldn't be used, would likely be the best approach.

Comment: Or `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) seems an ideal candidate indeed: "Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported."

Comment: When I add that exception the last line return null gives a compilation error because it's unreachable. Only solution I know to that is if(true) throw .... Is that an appropriate way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html), the reasons to deprecate an API include

> - It is insecure, buggy, or highly inefficient
> - It is going away in a future release
> - It encourages bad coding practices

neither of which actually fits your case.

Personally, I would favor throwing an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) which is already provided by the Standard Library in order to

> indicate that the requested operation is not supported.

To me, this sounds more like what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own interface which lists all the method you want users of your component to be able to access.  Make this the only interface they use and additional public methods will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Option (2) is good, but as you are following interfaces you'll want unchecked exceptions. And document the methods as unimplemented.

Deprecated implies a history, i.e., it works but should no longer be used. Since you are explicitly stating that the methods do not work, marking as deprecated will not prevent use nor indicate that the methods are unimplemented.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use some mix bag of design patterns. That will help you solve this problem efficiently and make the code maintainable as well.

Based on my knowledge, you can use the Abstract Factory pattern here. See the design sketch below in the figure.

[image]

Method1 and method2 in subclass1 and subclass2 are the ones which are supposed to be exposed while method3 and method4 in subclass1 and subclass2 are the ones which we don't want to expose.

Create a Genericsubclass interface and create some methods in this interface depending upon the nature of methods you have in subclasses. For ex: i have create one method in this interface called nonEventbasedmethod1

Create a factory corresponding to every sub class and each factory will implement the GenericSubclass interface. Then implementation of nonEventbasedmethod1 method in subclass1Factory would be some thing like

```
nonEventbasedmethod1(){
    subclass1.method1();
}
```

and implementation of nonEventbasedmethod1 method in subclass2Factory would be some thing like

```
nonEventbasedmethod1(){
    subclass2.method3();
}
```

Then create a SubclassAbstract Factory which will return one of the subclass factories and then without worrying about which factory has been returned (that decision has already been taken in SubclassAbstractFactory before returning the appropriate factory) simply call the desired method from GenericSubclass interface and underneath one of the methods from the subclass1 or subclass2 will be invoked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you plain to throw an exception for "NotSupported" or "NotImplemented" Exception - consider the exception of [NotImplementedException](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html) (at org.apache.commons). 
However, I would reconsider to revisit your design and see if you can avoid having this - maybe you need to define another interface, which will hold the methods that are always implemented, and extend it in another interface (or provide an interface with no extension to the previous one) for the methods you not always implement.